# using source control to create release notes?

Tags: version-control, svn, release-management

Lets say i have an off the shelf eccomerce cart. I put all the code inside subversion. I start to make changes and check the code changes back in.

is it possible to then display each "check in" with the developer messages so that i can make release notes?

I would like to use this for actual quoted time.

Comment: make sure your developers know their check in notes are not internal, but public!!

Comment: You are better off using an issue tracker for this, for starters not all commits are appropriate to display to a customer, and time may involve other factors as well

Comment: they may also contain notes about your software you dont want customers to see, or notes you dont want competitors to see

Answer (score 10):

As noted, `svn log` will get you this answer. But this really isn't suitable for time tracking -- just about all accounting systems need a hole for restatement, editing a svn commit description can be tricky if not impossible due to post-commit hooks.

You might want to look at something like redmine which integrates with SVN and has a time tracking feature built-in.

Answer (score 4):

[Check out `svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch03s06.html). It should do what you're after.

> ...the repository is like a time machine. It keeps a record of every change ever committed, and allows you to explore this history by examining previous versions of files and directories as well as the metadata that accompanies them... There are several commands that can provide you with historical data from the repository...
>
> To find out information about the history of a file or directory, use the `svn log` command. `svn` log will provide you with a record of who made changes to a file or directory, at what revision it changed, the time and date of that revision, and, if it was provided, the log message that accompanied the commit...
>
> If you want even more information about a file or directory, `svn log` also takes a `--verbose` (-v) switch. Because Subversion allows you to move and copy files and directories, it is important to be able to track path changes in the filesystem, so in verbose mode, `svn log` will include a list of changed paths in a revision in its output...